# Paypal Save Card on Android

Tags: android, rest, paypal

I'd like to use the [paypal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) for android in order to process real products available in my app. I would like the users to enter their card information only once, or at least only require a security code and for paypal to save these details so I need only send a token of some sort to refer to those saved details, rather than the user entering their card information again when purchasing a different product. Essentialy, I want to make the process of buying further products as easy as possible after the initial purchase.

Is this possible using the paypal SDK for android? or would I need to implement the [Paypal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) on my server, and communicate from the android to the server, and let that do the heavy lifting instead?

I actually don't understand the difference between the Paypal SDK for android, and the REST API available, as I imagine you could use both from android (using HttpClient for example)

Thank you,

Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are wanting to enable [future payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/) in your app. However, PayPal Mobile SDK 2.0+ only supports this feature as PayPal payments and not direct credit cards.

Currently if you wanted to store credit card details you would need to use [REST API and the Vault](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#vault).

Answer (score 0):

Paypal SDK: 
The PayPal Mobile SDKs enable native apps(Android, iOS) to easily accept PayPal and credit card payments.

For android: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

Paypal SDK is newer than PayPal Rest API, the best difference  is the speed to implement in your aplication.

PayPal Rest API:  include features like pre-approved payments, chained payments, and more support for non-U.S. accounts, and sometimes you really dont need that. And take more time de implementation.

I Recommend use Paypal SDK.